# Scala test traits with Mockito

Tags: scala, mockito

I'm new one in Scala. Currently I'm traing to implement a mock test for traits. Can somebody help me with implementation? I want to mock the methods seasonalityDao.doSomeForB and seasonalityDao.doSomeForB1 inside of the trait SeasonalityServiceImpl and test method hMock.doSomeForF().

Update:
I have corrected the code according comments below. In this case, when I try to veryfy mocked methods verify(sMock).doSomeForB() verify(sMock).doSomeForB1(), I receive next error:
*Wanted but not invoked:
seasonalityDao.doSomeForB();
-> at Main$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Main.scala:12)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.*

Here is a code(I have just simplified significant part of project for an example):

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.mockito.Mockito._

class Main extends FunSuite with SeasonalityServiceComponentImpl with SeasonalityDaoComponent {
  test("some test") {
    def hMock = mock(classOf[SeasonalityServiceImpl])
    def sMock = mock(classOf[SeasonalityDao])

    when(sMock.doSomeForB()).thenReturn(Option(2))
    when(sMock.doSomeForB1()).thenReturn(10)

    verify(sMock).doSomeForB()
    verify(sMock).doSomeForB1()

    println("With Option " + hMock.doSomeForF())
    println("Without Option " + hMock.doSomeForF1())
  }

  override def seasonalityDao: SeasonalityDao = mock(classOf[SeasonalityDao])

  override def seasonalityService: SeasonalityService = mock(classOf[SeasonalityService])
}

trait SeasonalityDaoComponent {
  def seasonalityDao: SeasonalityDao

  trait SeasonalityDao {
    def doSomeForB(): Option[Int]
    def doSomeForB1(): Int
  }
}

trait SeasonalityServiceComponent {
  def seasonalityService: SeasonalityService

  trait SeasonalityService {
    def doSomeForF(): Option[Int]
    def doSomeForF1(): Int
  }
}

trait SeasonalityServiceComponentImpl extends SeasonalityServiceComponent {
  this: SeasonalityDaoComponent =>

  trait SeasonalityServiceImpl extends SeasonalityService {
    def doSomeForF(): Option[Int] = {
      seasonalityDao.doSomeForB()
    }
    def doSomeForF1(): Int = {
      seasonalityDao.doSomeForB1()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How correct implement mock test for the SeasonalityServiceImpl? In this case I receive the message:Cannot mock/spy class Main$$anon$1
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:...

Comment: You should edit the question and add these errors. People will be more likely to answer.

As to the question itself, use `classOf[SeasonalityService]` instead of `seasonality.getClass`. That will use the interface, instead of the anonymous class you return below.

Comment: Thank you for advice! In case of classOf[SeasonalityService], I received: 
With Option null
Without Option 0

Returned default values, expected Option(2) and 10

Comment: Well, you forgot to mock that object (you're mocking `dMock` but testing `hMock`)

Comment: Iulian can you provide a code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you expect to have calls on your mock for `doSomeForB` and `doSomeForB1`. But your code verifies this expectation *before* you call them, so the test fails.

Moreover, your mocks are defined as local methods, meaning on each invocation you get a *new* mock object. You need to turn them into local vals, so you interact (and verify) the same instance.

Modify it to look like:

```
  test("some test") {
   // this seems unused -->>  def hMock = mock(classOf[SeasonalityServiceImpl])
    val sMock = mock(classOf[SeasonalityDao]) // you need it to be a val, not a def

    when(sMock.doSomeForB()).thenReturn(Option(2))
    when(sMock.doSomeForB1()).thenReturn(10)

    println("With Option " + sMock.doSomeForF()) // note that you should call them on sMock
    println("Without Option " + sMock.doSomeForF1())

    verify(sMock).doSomeForB()
    verify(sMock).doSomeForB1()
  }
```